# how to apply a config file site-wide?

Tags: php, web, configuration-files

I'm modifying a website and I would like to add a config file for it so that when when moving the website to another server, I only need to change environment parameters like database information only once. But I don't know how to apply the config file for the whole site. I tried to use include_once() and make it global using keyword global but it only works in the current file. If I don't use define() to make these parameters as constant, are there any other way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with `define`?

Comment: you would have to include the config file in each page you want to access the config file. If you have another file that you are including everywhere, you can include the config file in that. Other than that there is the auto_prepend_file directive you can set in php.ini to automatically include a file before every php page. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: @Mike define is fine. But when I was doing my research online, it seems that define could do the trick but is not recommended. So I just want to know some other simple ways to achieve this.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I thought there is an elegant way to include config file just once. I think I may need to use auto_prepend_file in my situation. Thank you Jonathan.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with defining constants in a configuration file. Just keep them all together in one spot and not have them scattered around everywhere.

Comment: include means that the file will be included in the current loaded script. include_once means that if you include more than once on the same file, the file is included only on the first call and subsequent include_once are ignored. this is useful, for example, when you have a function defined in a script that gets included. if the script was included more than once you would get an error saying "function already defined". include_once would ignore the 2nd and later include_once. *_once does not mean include this script in all other scripts. that would be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class `Config` and store your config parameters as [Class Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php). Then include this class everywhere you need it, or use [Autoload it](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

```
class Config {
    const databaseUsername = "user123";
    const databasePassword = "pass456";
}

echo Config::databaseUsername;
echo Config::databasePassword;
```

But as in my experience, `define()` works perfectly well, unless you need to store more complicated data types (arrays for example).

To avoid include the config file everywhere, you could set `auto_prepend_file` in your [PHP.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php), but I personally find this solution obscure, since it's not obvious for another developer working on your code that a PHP file is auto-included.

Comment: I believe the problem is that he has several scripts and doesn't want to add `include("config.php")` into every script. He was looking for an elegant solution to including a config file in every script without having to edit every script.

Comment: but if I autoload the class, I still need to write _autoload function in every file, right?

Comment: @tonyaziten yes, or at least write autoload to one file and include that everywhere.

Comment: @tonyaziten You either need to include your config file (class, or `define`s) everywhere, or include a file with an autoloader everywhere. In both cases, you need to include a file in all other files.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean @JonathanKuhn. Thank you Jonathan and Mathieu, I think I may just use define, which seems the simplest way so far.

Comment: @tonyaziten define isn't site-wide either. a file with a bunch of `define("CONFIG_FOO","bar")` will still need to be included on every page or in a prepend file. The difference between define and using the class that Mathieu suggested are minimal and both have the same benefits on things like scope. The only real benefit to Mathieu's suggestion is __autoload, which would allow you to dynamically load more than just a config class, but any class dynamically. This is really only helpful though if you are writing classes for your scripts and probably future-proof as you should move to oop.